# Why does FindDistribution give nonrepeatable results for fit parameters?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

When this cell is executed:

```
data = {1.67655096, 1.73234376, 1.8965016, 2.06723664, 
   2.19692088, 2.20885056, 2.21420304, 2.2199184, 2.25389304, 
   2.26954224, 2.42848368, 2.62902024, 2.6572795, 
   2.76596208, 2.95570296, 3.15574056, 3.25290168, 
   3.5498736, 3.81037608, 3.88707984, 4.00737456,
    4.1241312, 4.34081592, 4.56303456, 4.57950024};
FindDistribution[data, TargetFunctions -> {LogNormalDistribution}]
FindDistribution[data, TargetFunctions -> {LogNormalDistribution}]
FindDistribution[data, TargetFunctions -> {LogNormalDistribution}]
```

the fitted values for `mu` and `sigma` are different for each `FindDistribution`. Why? Can one get the estimated uncertainties of the fitted values from a large number of these different fitted values?

Comment: use the option `RandomSeeding->1` to get the same results in all three runs.

Comment: On *Mathematica* 11.1.1 (Windows 7) I get the same results for each.

Comment: I'm running Mathematica 11.2.0 on mac.

Comment: Does anyone know exactly how FindDistribution works?

Comment: Giving the different fitted values might be helpful.  (If this is a bug, then when reporting that to Wolfram, you'll certainly be more convincing with those values.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't know what `FindDistribution` is doing because it doesn't produce estimates that match any of those produced by `FindDistributionParameters`.  I avoid `FindDistribution` because it is much more of a black box with minimal documentation.  (A Bayesian prior is involved.  From the documentation: *The internal information criterion uses a Bayesian information criterion together with priors over `TargetFunctions`*. There's nothing wrong with assuming some Bayesian prior but the documentation is lacking in any details about that. I'm more of a conservative statistician so I think its options are more along the line of "wishful thinking" given that it allows a hodgepodge of fits, finds the best fit among the candidate models but then does not account for or warn about the fishing expedition it has done.)

`FindDistributionParameters` will get you the maximum likelihood estimates but not measures of precision:

```
mle = FindDistributionParameters[data, LogNormalDistribution[μ, σ]]
(* {μ -> 1.0309, σ -> 0.30526} *)
```

One can use the `LogLikelihood` function to get estimates of the standard errors:

```
logL = LogLikelihood[LogNormalDistribution[μ, σ], data];
cov = -Inverse[(D[logL, {{μ, σ}, 2}]) /. mle];
seμ = cov[[1, 1]]^0.5
(* 0.0610519 *)
seσ = cov[[2, 2]]^0.5
(* 0.0431702 *)
```

Comment: Did you mean to say "FindDistribution" instead of "FittedDistribution?"

Comment: Oops!  Thanks for catching that.  I'll change it.